# Android Market says my app is French, but it's English

Tags: android, google-play

I've recently published my application to the android market, however it is "incompatable" with many devices:

- HTC Wildfire w/Cyanogen 7 (Android 2.3) which I used for Development
- Sony Xperia X10 Mini Pro Locked to T-Mobile

The only thing I can think of why, is this:

> Localized to: default, French

But my App is English, so I don't understand why it's not showing on either device.

Many thanks will be appreciated,

Joe

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I emailed Android Support and got a response from Google,
the problem was the application was telling Android Market that the application was only supported on 'normal' sized screens, and I needed to add a  element to my Manifest.

Thanks anyways,

Joe

Comment: and what was that exactly you added?

Comment: I think it was the <supports-screen> element

Answer (score 0):

That means that you have two sets of resources, a default set and a French set.  It doesn't mean that French is the default.

For example, my app shows as

> Localized to: default, English (United States)

My default resources are in UK English and I have some additional files that account for different spellings in US English.

Other apps where I have only one set of resources show as

> Localized to: default

The reason it shows as "default" is because Android has no way of specifying which language you are using for the default resources.  Default is merely used for every locale that doesn't have a more specific set of resources available.  So this won't be the reason for your app not showing up.  Country filtering is done further down in the "Publishing options" section.

The filtering that is causing you a problem is more likely to be to do with hardware features or Android platform version.

Comment: This apk requests 1 features that will be used for Android Market filtering
android.hardware.touchscreen
REQUIRES ANDROID:
1.5 and up

Comment: @Joe Sounds like it should work then.  Perhaps you could post a link to your app and then maybe a few people can check whether it is working for them.

Answer (score -1):

Check your `strings.xml`. Does it contain any French language strings?

Comment: More about localization http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/localization.html